# Angular 4 using a service in routing module

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

I'm trying to make a simple CMS system using a Laravel REST API. For the front-end i'm using the Angular 4 framework & angular CLI. Now i'm trying to generate dynamic routes (fetching pages from the API by using a service & generating routes for each of these pages). I tried this with a local data simulation and got this working like this.

**Routing.module.ts**

```
let cmsService: CmsService = new CmsService();
const pages = cmsService.getPageNames();

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: OverviewComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent}
];

for (let i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
  routes.push(
    { path: pages[i].toString(), component: PageEditComponent}
  );
}
```

I know this probably isn't the best way of doing thing but it worked. Now i have to inject HTTP and the whole thing came down because the following isn't working anymore since it's expecting to get http injected.

```
let cmsService: CmsService = new CmsService();
```

I could probably just pass it by making the http variable in someway but it feels kinda dirty. So i started wondering if there wasn't an easier way of doing this. For example injecting the service like you're supposed to instead of creating a new service. And create routes for the pages retrieved in this way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: IIRC you should not instanciate services like that. If you cannot use the constructor to inject them, use the injector: let cmsService= injector.get(CmsService); Docs: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

Comment: That's what i'm trying to do now but i can't seem to get it to work. Using the ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate

Comment: I'm now getting an error: No provider for Http! I'm probably pretty close but looking over something. And when i add Http to the resolveAndCreate i get the following error: No provider for ConnectionBackend!  @Tim

Comment: Have you imported HttpClientModule (angular 4.3+) or HttpModule (< Angular 4.3) in your app.module ?

Comment: I had the HttpModule imported, tried to import both, tried to import only HttpClientModule still the same error :( @Tim